# jQuery to change href that includes shortcode

Tags: jquery, wordpress

When I click on a link that includes a shortcode, I want to change the href by removing any spaces. Here's the link

```
<div class='strip_space'>
   <a href="https://example.com/[wpbb site:user_meta key='contrib-name']">Testing</a>
</div>
```

I've gotten this far

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(".strip_space").html(function () {
      this.href = this.href.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return jQuery(this).href().
            });
        });
```

What am I missing?

Cheers, Richard

Here's the snippet I'm using for enqueueing

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'strip-space', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/strip-space.js',
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
  }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`attr(attributeName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and target the `<a>` instead of the `<div>`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".strip_space a").attr('href', function(_, curr) {
    return curr.replace(/\s/g, '');
  });
  // display as text for demo purpose
  $(".strip_space a").text(function(){ return this.href})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='strip_space'>
  <a href="https://example.com/[wpbb site:user_meta key='contrib-name']">Testing</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! The <script src=... line killed my Beaver Builder editor. So I took it out and everything still works. But I'm wondering if it's somehow temporarily cached and will stop working when the cache clears. Any suggestions on how I should incorporate the <script src=... line?

Comment: I know nothing about Beaver builder